# LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter not work

Tags: ros, laser-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I tried to bound the angle of LaserScan output  from -1.57~+1.57 to -0.5~+0.5.
But it just not work..  Here is my yaml.

```
    $ cat my_laser_config.yaml 
    scan_filter_chain:
    - name: angular_bounds
      type: LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter
      params:
        lower_angle: -0.5
        upper_angle: 0.5
```

The output topic "/scan_filtered" is still the same messages with input topic..
Any suggestion??

Kevin Kuei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220140/laserscanangularboundsfilter-not-work/) by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That project seems to be out of maintained.
I just wrote my custom angular bound filter, and it works fine

https://github.com/wennycooper/learning_nav/blob/master/src/mybot_laser_angular_bound_filter.cpp

---

Originally posted by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) with karma: 159 on 2015-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-03-06**:
Hi Mr. Kuei. Could you please looking at your e mail?